# Searching for single record in JSON data (Android app)

Tags: android, json, database, parsing

So, in my app, I am retrieving JSON data and parsing it. RIght now, it is displaying every record on a textView like this

Name: Eric
Email: Eric.com

Name: Greg
Email: Greg@Greg.com

.................. etc

Code:

```
  //parse json data
 try {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

       s = s + 
               "Name : "+json.getString("Name")+"\n"+
               "Email : "+json.getString("Email")+"\n\n";
   }

   resultView.setText(s);
```

I want to be able to search and display only a single record, e.g. Eric's record. How could I do this? I tried this adding `if (json.getString("Name") == "Eric") { }` like this:

```
//parse json data
 try {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           if (json.getString("Name") == "Eric) { //added if statement
       s = s + 
               "Name : "+json.getString("Name")+"\n"+
               "Email : "+json.getString("Email")+"\n\n";
               }
   }

   resultView.setText(s);
```

but it doesn't display anything, then. Any ideas on how I can search for a single person's record in JSON? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
json.getString("Name") == "Eric"
```

to

```
json.getString("Name").equals("Eric")
```

When comparing `String` you should use `equals` not `==`

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Dumb mistakes, always get me!

Answer (score 1):

## Use

```
json.getString("Name").equals("Eric")
```

do not use ==,as basically it is used to compare int value and you are comparing string.